# Stick footer to bottom even after body loads

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react application that has a `<Footer />` component at the end of the main component. The footer component is as simple as:

```
import React from 'react';

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className="footer">
            Copyrights Reserved © {new Date().getFullYear()}
        </footer>
    );
}

export default Footer;
```

I have managed to stick it to the bottom using the following styling:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #282c34;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Now, I have a component `<Body />` that starts empty, and then fills itself with data it receives later from a remote call, when this happens, the component goes beyond the footer, as the footer fails to keep sticking to the bottom.

Some of things I tried were:

1. Add `margin-top: 100vh;` instead of `bottom: 0;`, but there were a huge empty gap above the footer.
2. Add `height: 100%` to the body, but didn't seem to change anything.
3. Refresh the component, but that leads to also refreshing the Body component.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try to give min-height to div inside of the Body component

Answer (score 0):

If you use flex, just add the `flex:1` style to your Body component, even when data is not loaded yet.
Event when it's empty, it's going to take all the available space and the footer will be at the bottom.

Comment: I don't use flex, but I tried `height: 100%` but it doesn't seem to change anything.